# Hadoop Distcp: Input size is greater then output size

Tags: hadoop, distcp

I am copying a folder from one path to another, basically creating a backup.
The source(input) folder size is 5 TB. I use the following distcp command to copy:

```
hadoop distcp -m 150 <source_folder_path> <destination_folder_path>
hadoop fs -du -s -h source_folder
hadoop fs -du -s -h destination_folder
hadoop fs -ls source_folder | wc -l
hadoop fs -ls destination_folder | wc -l
```

This is within the same cluster.
I am unable to understand as why my input folder is 5 tb and output folder is only 1 tb. The job completes successfully without any error.
Also I see that the number of files is same in input and output.
I don't use compression or anything in the process. Can someone point out to me why is it like this.
Hadoop version is 2.7

Comment: include the actual command in your question. Command that you used to count folder size. and the output is also preferred. cluster address not needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my command list

Comment: with the information you provided by now,  few debug suggestions  can be done. 
the most simple would be 
```hadoop fs -ls -R  source_folder   |  sort -k5 -n```
```hadoop fs -ls -R  destination_folder   |  sort -k5 -n```
which will help you find out difference on large size files

Comment: Can you post the full out put of the two du commands too?

Comment: Its too big. 6k directories.